# Is Lync 2013 Client SDK compatible with Skype for Business?

Tags: lync, skype-for-business

We have made an application which use the Lync 2013 Client SDK to interact with people depending on some status.

The IT department just asked me if they can allow the upgrade to the `Skype for Business`. Currently I can't find the Client SDK for the Skype for Business.

1. Will my application using Lync 2013 Client SDK still works?
2. If no, what have I to do? Is there a client SDK somewhere I didn't found? Or it's not existing anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated to Skype For Business and my current app on Lync 2013 works fine. It looks to support all the existing methods/APIs.

Update:
While the SDK works fine, if you are docking the new Lync (or SFB) conversation window you may require changes to your WPF code to support the new UI.
We had to move to previous UI (Lync) just to get the docking working since the customer is still on Lync.

Answer (score 1):

Skype for Business client is just a rebranded Lync 2013 client.
If you look at the "About Skype for Business" page in the client, it still calls itself Microsoft Lync 2013

Answer (score 0):

I created a new application to interact with Skype for Business (Office 365). I found the Lync 2013 SDK did not initially work with the application.

After installing Lync 2013 onto the computer, however, it worked fine.

Note that it won't work if I uninstall Lync 2013. But the presence of Lync 2013 on the computer doesn't seem to affect Skype for Business.