# Can't install Lync 2013 SDK with Skype for Business 2016

Tags: c#, sdk, client, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to make a simple WinForms application that changes Skype for Business status (I'm using Skype for Business 2016). According to the links below, I should be able to install the Lync 2013 SDK (which I'm finding here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36824 ). But when I attempt to install it, it says `Microsoft Lync 2013 not found. Go here to download and install: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=248583`. Any suggestions? Do I have to also have Lync installed in order to interact with Skype for Business 2016?

[Is Lync 2013 Client SDK compatible with Skype for Business?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123307/is-lync-2013-client-sdk-compatible-with-skype-for-business)

[No client SDK for Skype for Business 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229251/no-client-sdk-for-skype-for-business-2016)

Comment: The below answers are likely solutions, but I noticed something else that may work for someone in the future: when this message box shows up, instead of clicking "OK", click the "Close" button on the Message Box. `Note that I did this after following @sri-chandrasekaran-microsoft 's solution`

Comment: Just to elaborate the answer above this one, **lyncsdk.exe** is actually a wrapper containing msi installation files. You can unpack it using winrar or 7-zip or some other zip program, then use one of the extracted installers to set up the SDK. This is what it looks like with WinRar: [Right click on lyncsdk.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa2ZM.jpg), then [choose your installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVAoS.jpg).

Comment: The only reason that worked for you is specifically because by downloading and installing Skype For Business 15 you're also installing the Lync.dll files. Otherwise clicking the "x" does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. The current work around is to install with a Skype for Business 15 client and then do the client upgrade

Comment: This is the least convenient work around listed on this page. If anyone is experiencing this issue and looking for a work around simply extract the .msi from the LyncSDK.exe and it'll install just fine without the need to rollback an upgrade or having to change any registry keys.

Answer (score 16):

A simple solution is to extract the .exe installer with 7-zip or some other program. After you unzip it, just run the corresponding .msi installers.

Comment: Can you provide some more detailed steps on this? Which installer you're referring to? And which .msi's to run?

Comment: @derekantrican There are only 3 files in the entire .exe. When you extract the .exe simply choose the LyncSDK.msi file that corresponds to your system architecture, 32-bit or 64-bit.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need Lync 2013, but the installer thinks you do and checks for it. It checks a couple different registry keys looking for it, so if you fake one of them you can get past the check:

- Open regedit
- Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync` (create any keys along the way if necessary)
- Create a new string value named `InstallationDirectory`; the data doesn't matter
- Run the SDK installer
- Once it's finished, undo your changes to the registry

---

If you don't want to navigate around regedit manually, this registry script will create the appropriate key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync]
"InstallationDirectory"=""
```