# Lync.Model reference for Skype for Business 2016 Online Status

Tags: c#, asp.net, skype-for-business

i have Skype for Business 2016 installed on my computer.

i want to reach its online status via Lync SDK 2013.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
   {

        var theClient = LyncClient.GetClient();
        Console.WriteLine(theClient.State);

        Console.ReadLine();
   }
```

i have my mail adress in `theClient` and

```
theClient.State
```

is

```
 SignedIn
```

how can i reach online/away/busy statuses with Lync SDK.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer:

Download SDK from here
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36824

install and look [Can't install Lync 2013 SDK with Skype for Business 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978074/cant-install-lync-2013-sdk-with-skype-for-business-2016)

> A simple solution is to extract the .exe installer with 7-zip  or
>   some other program. After you unzip it, just run the corresponding
>   .msi installers.

go to folder:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\Assemblies\Desktop

find "Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll" add "Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll" to project as reference.

if you want to check your status :https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/08/microsoft-lync-desktop-development-how-to-get-started/

```
var theClient = LyncClient.GetClient();
Contact self = theClient.Self.Contact;
object obj = self.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.Availability);
string stringval=self.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.Availability).ToString();
```

if you want to check other person's status via e-mail

```
 Contact contact = theClient.ContactManager.GetContactByUri("xx@example.com");
 object zzz = contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.Availability);
```

These are the stringval values=
https://rcosic.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/availability-presence-in-lync-client/

```
Invalid (-1),
None (0) – Do not use this enumerator. This flag indicates that the cotact state is unspecified.,
Free (3500) – A flag indicating that the contact is available,
FreeIdle (5000) – Contact is free but inactive,
Busy (6500) – A flag indicating that the contact is busy and inactive,
BusyIdle (7500) – Contact is busy but inactive,
DoNotDisturb (9500) – A flag indicating that the contact does not want to be disturbed,
TemporarilyAway (12500) – A flag indicating that the contact is temporarily away,
Away (15500) – A flag indicating that the contact is away,
Offline (18500) – A flag indicating that the contact is signed out.
```

FULL CODE (i put inside timer ):

```
using Microsoft.Lync.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace UserStatus
{
    public class DoThis
    {

        private readonly Timer _timer;
        public DoThis()
        {
            _timer = new Timer(1000 * 2) { AutoReset = true };
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        }
        private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoThis2();
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            _timer.Stop();
        }

        void DoThis2()
        {

            Stop();

            var theClient = LyncClient.GetClient();
            Contact self = theClient.Self.Contact;


            if ((self.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.Availability)).ToString() == "6500")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("busy");
            }
            if ((self.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.Availability)).ToString() == "3500")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("available");
            }
            if ((self.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.Availability)).ToString() == "15500")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("away");
            }

            Start();
        }
    }
}
```